# (Neo4j, Cypher) How to set incremental number to relationships?

Tags: neo4j

i'm using neo4j. what i'd like to do is to create a root node for search result and to create relationships from root node to search result nodes. and I'd like to set incremental number to each relationship's property.
if possible, with one query.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I doesn't make sense to me. You're search for something you will then create?

Comment: All the nodes are for search results? What distinguishes the root node? And how do you know which nodes should be connected to the root node? You really need to add a lot more information. In fact, you should at least provide a data model and the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not explaining enough.
This is what I'd like to do.
Any more concise way?

```
// create test data
WITH RANGE(0, 99) AS indexes,
['Paul', 'Bley', 'Bill', 'Evans', 'Robert', 'Glasper', 'Chihiro', 'Yamanaka', 'Fred', 'Hersch'] AS names
UNWIND indexes AS index
CREATE (p:Person { index: index, name: (names[index%10] + toString(index)) });

// create 'Results' node with relationships to search result 'Person' nodes.
// 'SEARCH_RESULT' relationships have 'order' and 'orderBy' properties.
CREATE(x:Results{ts: TIMESTAMP()})
WITH x
MATCH(p:Person)
WHERE p.name contains '1'
MERGE(x)-[r:SEARCH_RESULT]->(p)
WITH x, r, p
MATCH (x)-[r]->(p)
WITH x, r, p
ORDER BY p.name desc
WITH  RANGE(0, COUNT(r)-1) AS indexes, COLLECT(r) AS rels
UNWIND indexes AS i
SET (rels[i]).order = i
SET (rels[i]).orderBy = 'name'
RETURN rels;

// validate
MATCH(x:Results)-[r:SEARCH_RESULT]->(p:Person)
RETURN r, p.name ORDER BY r.order;
```